# Is there any way to handle an inaccessible exception?

Tags: c#, silverlight, exception

In a Silverlight 4 app I am calling a function on an included control (DataGrid), and this function sometimes throws a spurious exception of type `MS.Internal.WrappedException`. Since this exception is meaningless, I need to swallow it. Unfortunately, the exception is declared `internal class WrappedException : Exception` in System.Windows.dll, so I can't name it in a `catch` block.

The question is, what is the safest way to detect this exception and ignore it? The two options I've come up with are:

1. Look for the original exception: `ex.InnerException is InvalidOperationException`
2. Look for the name: `ex.GetType().FullName == "MS.Internal.WrappedException"`

Is one way better than the other? Is there another option I didn't think of?

Here's my function showing the different options:

```
    private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedAlarm = alarmList.SelectedItem as Alarm;
        if (selectedAlarm != null)
        {
            dataGrid.SelectedItem = selectedAlarm.Source;
            try
            {
                dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.SelectedItem, null);
            }
            // catch (MS.Internal.WrappedException ex) doesn't compile
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.InnerException is InvalidOperationException) // 1
                if (ex.GetType().FullName == "MS.Internal.WrappedException") // 2
                {
                    // ignore exception
                }
                else
                    throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

For those who are interested, here's the StackTrace:

```
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.InsertDisplayedElement(Int32 slot, UIElement element, Boolean wasNewlyAdded, Boolean updateSlotInformation)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.InsertDisplayedElement(Int32 slot, Boolean updateSlotInformation)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.GetExactSlotElementHeight(Int32 slot)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.ScrollSlotIntoView(Int32 slot, Boolean scrolledHorizontally)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.ScrollSlotIntoView(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 slot, Boolean forCurrentCellChange, Boolean forceHorizontalScroll)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(Object item, DataGridColumn column)
   at DtDemo.Home.alarmList_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

and here's InnerException.StackTrace:

```
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.get_ActualDetailsVisibility()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.OnApplyTemplate()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnApplyTemplate(IntPtr nativeTarget)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer the test for `ex.InnerException is InvalidOperationException`, and also possibly checking some of the properties of the InnerException.

It's a subjective judgement, though.  It somehow feels less 'hacky', and maybe less likely to break in a future version.  Do you think Microsoft is more likely to change the namespace or class name of their internal wrapper class, or do something like just throw the `InvalidOperationException` without wrapping it?

Of course, ideally you could stop the exception from being thrown in the first place. I'm sure you've already exhausted this route.

Comment: I'm not sure what props of `InternalException` to check. The message is localized, so that's useless. I certainly don't want to rely on a stack trace!

Answer (score 6):

This is intentional, so you don't try to catch this exception.  It is a serious one, it is not meaningless, do *not* ignore it.  Fix the real problem.  I can't help you diagnose the reason without a stack trace.

Comment: I strongly agree; this is a critical internal exception from DataGrid telling you that the call to ScrollIntoView has failed and may have placed the control into an invalid state.  If it's not a critical exception, then it's a serious bug in the control (this is less likely.)

Comment: The app works fine once the exception is ignored, and I can't imagine how to go about debugging the problem, but I've posted the stack traces from the exception in case someone can help.

Comment: @Gabe, try calling DataGrid.UpdateLayout() before the call to ScrollIntoView().  I did some reading and there are currently some known bugs in the DataGrid related to virtualization that can cause problems with ScrollIntoView().

Comment: Okay, I agree, this smells like a bug or a condition they just didn't count on.  Nothing like a threading problem or a critical Windows error.  A perfectly good waste of a WrappedException ;)

Comment: I would have to argue that it should *never* be intentional to expose an internal exception type. I would consider it a bug for any public interface to throw a non-public exception type.

Comment: Best laid plans going astray.  Be sure to send your feedback to connect.microsoft.com.  It kinda matters, fast evolving products like Silverlight are always in some kind of semi-broken state.  Version 5 coming up soon.

Comment: @Dan: DataGrid.UpdateLayout() certainly makes a difference! I don't know if it solves my problem or just makes it harder to reproduce, but I'll use it in conjunction with my crappy exception handler.

Comment: I'm going to guess that this is a minor variation of https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/596822/datagrid-argumentoutofrangeexception-in-scrollintoview-after-refreshing-itemssource

Comment: @Gabe - I'm curious about this, you definitely sound like you know what you are talking about.  This is a nasty show-stopper, I'm guessing you probably already spent way more time on this then you care for.  It is a liability with using software you can't control.  I've lost some precious weeks of my life with that myself.  What's your call here?  Is this something you run into with Silverlight just a wee bit too often or is this just an outlier?

Comment: Hans: This app is actually a demo, meaning that nobody will notice if the selected item doesn't scroll into view (the exception only hits at startup), but a fatal exception is Bad. If this was really a showstopper, I would end up copying huge blobs of code from Reflector and patching up the problem sections or just write my own control from scratch (like I did with the chart control).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I should actually read the entire post.

I'd vote for using reflection (option #2).

I would argue that this is bug that should be reported to Microsoft: the public interface of an assembly shouldn't be throwing internal or private exceptions to its consumer.